# Solve the equations for $0\leq x<2\pi$, note $x$ is in radians.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> a. $2\sin3x-1=0$
>
> b. $\sec^2x-2\tan x=4$
>
> c. $2\sin^2x+3\cos x-3=0$
>
> d. $2\cos(3x-1)=0$

For a., I know that you have to bring the $1$ to the right and divide by $2$, but that's about it. Can someone please explain how to solve these four questions step-by-step without the use of a calculator?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: d) is basically same as a), you should know how to solve these

Comment: Do you mean for (a) to read $2\sin(3x-1)=0$?

Comment: @amWhy, nope! Nice call though.

Comment: Just thought I'd check!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

b) $\sec^2 x=1+\tan^2 x$. Then, solve the resulting quadratic equation.

c) $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x$. Then, solve the resulting quadratic equation.

Comment: Oh, I should have looked at those Pythagorean identities. Thanks!

Comment: @C.Guan As a member of this site , don't inculcate a bad habit (inculcated by almost 50% people here) of leaving answers unaccepted!

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying your method! Also, I have 1 more minute to wait in order to accept.

Comment: @C.Guan Thanks..And welcome to try out... Don't hesitate to ask if you have any doubt..

Comment: Cool! Thanks again!

Comment: My teacher expects me to do this without a calculator, but for b) one of the answers I got is something I cannot possibly get without a calculator. Is it possible that I did something incorrect? I end up with $(\tan x-3)(\tan x+1)=0$.

Comment: For the second factor, I get $x= 3\pi /4$.

Comment: Or for these questions, is there only one solution to each one? If there is only one solution, I'm good.

Comment: @C.Guan As for b), the answer set is $x=\{\tan^{-1}(3),{3\pi\over 4}\}$ with $x\in [0,2\pi]$. IN most cases, this form of answer is enough. You dont need to calculate accurately the value of the angle in radians (or degrees).

Comment: Oh! Thanks! @Qwerty

Answer (score 1):

a) Can you draw a right triangle with hypotenuse of length 1 and another side of length $\frac{1}{2}$?

d) Same idea but now the triangle has long side 1, side close to you 1 and a right angle? Hint: Pythagoras!

Comment: Hey, I'm a bit confused by the second part of your answer. Can you please clarify? And "side close to you": what does this mean?

Comment: Imagine a triangle ABC, with AB being the long side, angle BCA = 90 (so AC and BC make a right angle intersection). Then side close to you would be AC, opposite site BC. You are right, the naming isn't great :)

Comment: But how is it possible for a triangle to have a hypotenuse of 1 and another side of length of 1? Or is that the point?

Comment: That is indeed the point - if AB = 1 and AC =1 implies that BC = 0. What is then the angle BAC?

Comment: Angle BAC is 0! I think?

Comment: Yes! This is equivalent with saying that $\cos(3x -1) = 0 \iff 3x -1 = 0 + n\pi$ where $n$ is a whole number.

Answer (score 1):

**Further hints:**
\begin{align*}
\sin x&=\sin\theta\iff x\equiv\begin{cases}
\theta\\\pi-\theta\end{cases}\mod 2\pi,\\
\cos x&=0\iff x\equiv \frac\pi2\mod\pi.
\end{align*}